# DML not allowed in page action

Tags: visualforce, dml

So I understand DML Operations aren't allowed in `getters/setters,constructors` but it was my understanding that they were allowed in methods that were invoked by page-actions like so:

page:

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller" action="{!init}">...</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public mycontroller(){
   public void init(){
        //perform some DML, in my case inserting a custom setting if one doesn't exist...
        insert whatever...;
   }
}
```

This worked fine for a while, but than when I attempted to deploy my app into a Spring '13 sandbox org I get an exception:

> DML currently not allowed  An unexpected error has occurred. Your
>   development organization has been notified.

*Has this always been the case and I'm doing something different I didn't realize*?

If not some suggestions how I could create my necessary custom settings if they don't exist on page-init would be great.

Comment: I can use DML in a page action in a Winter '13 DE without any problem, so if it isn't working it is new in Spring '13.  Is it in a component?  Then you need to specify the [allowDML="true"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_component.htm).

Comment: It's not in a component, it's in a page that is loaded inside of a visualforce tab though...

Comment: Works for me in a VF tab as well in a Winter '13 DE.  Seems like it should "just work" if you haven't changed API versions of the page, class, or anything like that.

Comment: This is weird. I just moved the location of the call and it's working for me as well! Ok -- going to leave this for the moment until I figure it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I once started seeing this error and couldn't work out for the life of me why... I eventually realised I was being a bit dim, and following my oft-used practice had a call to Init() inside a constructor, and you can't perform DML operations like this inside the constructor!

**Update Jan 2014 - Something else to watch out for!**

Almost a year after writing this answer I hit a similar issue yesterday, this time because the controller was for a Visualforce component as opposed to a page. In a component you must explicitly allow DML like so:

```
<apex:component controller="myController" allowDML="true">
```

Comment: Nice caveat @LaceySnr! How do you get these pages and components through Security Review process with DML in the action? Did you need to justify an exceptional case to them?

Comment: This is just in an action fired from a button, not on load. I do have one on load though and yes, I just had to explain that the auto-test reported a false positive and that the DML would be in no way damaging to system data.

Comment: I had this same problem with an action button and this solution worked for me.