# DML not allowed in page action when nothing happens in constructor

Tags: visualforce, controller

This question may similar to [DML not allowed in page action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/dml-not-allowed-in-page-action) but I can't resolve it.

This is my page:

```
<apex:page Controller="MyController" 
           action="/{!MyAction}"> 
Page loading... 
</apex:page>
```

and this is my controller

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public PageReference MyAction() {
        // ...
        // update something in DB
        // ...
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + this.opportunityId);
        return page;
    }
}
```

I get `DML not allowed in page action` but my constructor is empty.

Any tips?

Comment: I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: @mast0r sorry for the typo

Comment: Is "DML not allowed in page action" the exact text of the error message - that is different to the constructor and suggests that you can't update the database from the page action method.

Comment: Why that `/` in the action?

Comment: @mast0r custom controller and the / is in the extension because it has to be. It ends up landing on an opportunity page.  That part is ok, it's the update the database part that kills it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is because you have the page action attribute as:

```
action="/{!MyAction}"
```

the slash that precedes the {!MyAction} merge field means that the {!MyAction} will be treated as a getter.  The method you have posted is named getUpdateAndRedirectToPage, so it satisfies the getter requirements (assuming that MyAction is just an example?).

DML isn't allowed in getters, so I'd expect an error of 'DML not currently allowed' or similar.  If you remove the '/', the method will be executed as a page action and DML will be allowed (although not necessarily recommended, due to the lack of order of execution guarantees).

Comment: Great spot Bob!

Comment: Just tried to save the page with a slash and then - oops, got the same error! Nice to know Bob! But where is this (using slash) documented?

Comment: Its not the using slash so much as the page action is taken as a URL rather than an action method due to the literal component.  Then anything in merge syntax is evaluated as a string and concatenated.