# How to Update Record on Page Load without Getting XSRF

Tags: csrf

How can we update records when the page loads without getting the Cross Site Request Forgery security issue?

It would be good if it's explained for Classic and Lightning interface.

Thanks

Comment: for classic it maybe execution of some remoting action with DML after page has been loaded

Comment: I think that by definition that's impossible. In a Visualforce page, you could put an action attribute in the page tag, but you probably shouldn't be performing a record update with that action.

Comment: Yes, it's about performing Insert/Update in the action in page tag. The use case requires this step and I'm asking because of the security review that Salesforce conducts.

Comment: did you see: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/08/dml-during-initialisation.html? and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/dml-not-allowed-in-page-action ?